# Oracle: index vs. table stats

Tags: oracle, performance, statistics

In Oracle, when would I want to gather index stats, instead of just gathering stats on the table?  In which use case would index stats make a difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, I would not gather stats on indexes, I would gather stats on tables with cascade=>TRUE. But in 11g if you enable to maintenance job, it should gather stats for you, so unless you need stats generated a certain way you are probably ok with the default stats jobs that runs in the maintenance program.

Comment: and what would stats on an index do, vs. stats on the table?

Comment: Stats on an index will give the optimizer better statistics on cardinality of the data for that index. Ideally it will help Oracle to pick which indexes are the most useful.